# How to get a reference number BroadcastReceiver monodroid?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to get a reference number? The following code returns null:

```cs
[BroadcastReceiver]

[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class Telefon : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraState).Equals(TelephonyManager.ExtraStateOffhook))
        {
            string telephone = intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraPhoneNumber);

            Bundle bundle = intent.Extras;
            string telephone_2 = bundle.GetString("outgoing_number");

            Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(context, telephone + "\n" + telephone_2, ToastLength.Long); //return null;
            toast.Show();
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm not the best person to ask, but could you hardcode your strings?  This isn't exactly a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a.k.a. SSCCE).

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the right permissions?

Comment: Yes <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />